# Check that the reference is pointing to a specific object in C++

Tags: c++, reference, equality

How can I check that the reference is pointing to a specific object in C++?

I mean something like this:

```
int x(0);
int& xR = x;
if(xR == x)
{
//xR is refering to x
}
else
{
//xR is not refering to x
}
```

Comment: `if(&xR == &x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class T> T* addressof (T& ref) noexcept
```

This function returns the address of 
 ref even in the presence of an overloaded reference operator (operator&).

```
if(std::addressof(xR) == std::addressof(x)) 
{ 
      yadayadayada 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

They will have the same address.

```
if( &xR == &x )
{
//xR is referring to x
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: Note that `operator&` might be overloaded (depends on the type). If that is the case you can still use `std::addressof`.